# Move all elements in array after removing one with splice - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects each containing a name and adress. If I remove en element in this array (an object) with `splice()`, are the other elements moved "down" in the array so that no blanks are left in the array. If not how can you move all elements down one index in the array?

people is another array containing strings of names

My array looks like this:

```
var array = [0];

for (int i = 0; i < people.length; i++)
{
    array.push({
        name: people[i],
        adress: "adress"
    });
}
```

How I remove

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
{
    if (array[i].name == "some name")
    {
        array.splice(i, 1);
    }
}
```

Will this leave the array with a blank index somewhere in it, or are the other elements moved when `splice()`is called. I have looked over the documentation but I can't find an answer to this.

Comment: Always check the docs for this sort of thing - MDN is a great resource: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice. To answer your question, yes, everything will move 'down' to fill the space emptied by splice().

Comment: If you have questions like this, you can experiment with js fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you find out the answer for this:

```
console.log(array);

for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
{
  if (array[i].name == "some name")
    {
      array.splice(i, 1);
  }
}

console.log(array);
```

Check out the console log before and after the `for` loop to see what happened. Playing with live code is the best possible way to learn.

Lastly, as stated in my comment, MDN's docs are exhaustive - you can always reference them if you're unsure what something does in JS. Here's the article pertinent to your question - documentation for `Array.prototype.slice()`:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice